# How to use Multidimensional Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to use multi dimensional arrays in a project I am doing, and I cannot figure out how to code it.

I have 3 things I want to store, a single string called "attribute name", another single string called "attribute type" and a collection of strings called "attributeOptions".

So if I had the data, attribute name="Brand", attribute type="sports", attribute options="nike|addidas|puma", I would want to be able to input and extract all of this information at once using a loop.

Am I thinking about multidimensional arrays the wrong way or how would I go about coding this in PHP?

Comment: Arrays can contain other array so the they are multidimensional

Comment: Are you getting your data from a database? I would be happy to show you some example code if you could provide a little bit more info about the data source.

Comment: The data source is a web form... I want to turn the information into a 3 dimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
$md = array (
    "name"  => "a",
    "attribute" => "type",
    "options"  => array("Nike", "etc0", "etc1") // Array
);



$array['name'] = 'a';
$array['attribute'] = 'type';
$array['options'][0] = 'Nike';
$array['options'][1] = 'Nike or Other';
$array['options'][2] = 'Nike or Other Other';
```

Or you could do

```
$array['name'] = 'a';
$array['attribute'] = 'type';
$array['options']['optionOne'] = 'Nike';
$array['options']['optionTwo'] = 'Nike or Other';
$array['options']['optionThree'] = 'Nike or Other Other';
```

See?

Comment: Assuming there are more than one of these, an outer array contains a collection of structures like `$fruits`. `array(array('name'=>'a','attribute'=>'type','options'=>array(1,2,3)), array('name'=>'b','attribute'=>'other','options'=>array(4,5,6)))`

Comment: But how would I initialise an array of this kind using a loop? So I could go "array[$i]['type']['options']= something

Comment: If I knew the form of the data you want to insert it would make it easier to show you exactly how.

Comment: So to be precise, how would I declare and not at all initalise an array that I could access like array[3][type][2] where its form would be attribute name, attribute type, attribute options? I want to initialise then whole array with a loop?

Comment: You can initialize just by assignment [i.e. Use it and it initializes], or initialize by declaration [i.e. $myArrayName = array();]

array() is a blanket statement for any *type* of array.  The system will resolve the details.

Make sense?

Comment: so to initalise a 3 dimesional array it would be $array=array(array(array)));??

Comment: No.

Just $array = array();  Then you can fill the $array variable with anything you want.